# How do I get a PHP query result into an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I know this is insanely easy, but I'm a noob and not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
1: $mysqli = new mysqli('test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
2: if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
3:     if (!$stmt->execute()) {
4:        $out .= "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
5:    }
6:    $out = $stmt->fetch_array();
7: } else {
8:   $out .= $mysqli->error;
9: }
```

I get a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()` error on line 6.

Comment: So where are you defining $query?

Comment: MySQLi statements don't have a `fetch_array()`. There's a `fetch()` method, which you may call after you have bound out variables with `bind_result()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) if you have PHP 5.3 or greater, then use [`mysql_result::fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $out .= "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($out = $res->fetch_array()) {
    }
else {
    $out .= $mysqli->error;
}
```

Also, you may want to check out all of the [MySQL-Improved documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

You can also fetch all rows at once with [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: Just to note, `get_result()` is PHP 5.3+ only, as it depends on the mysqlnd driver...

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to include a link to the php manual for this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php and to note that he will likely want to tie the `mysqli_stmt::get_result` call in with a call to `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Ok, this looks a lot easier than I was expecting. Will this handle multi-dimentional arrays?

Comment: @TravisHeeter I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why don't you try doing a `print_r($out);` using both `fetch_array()` and `fetch_all()` to see what kinds of arrays are returned.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee I will try that. I added your code, and I'm now getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_result() on a non-object`

Comment: Your query may have failed then.

Comment: I don't think the query failed. When I var_dump $stmt I get what I expected. Is there a framework or something that I can just say `querry_to_array($query_results);` and get an array back? I can't believe how difficult this is. All I'm trying to do is get the table names into a list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18382/discussion-between-travisheeter-and-geoff-montee)

Comment: @TravisHeeter it really is not difficult. I don't know what is going wrong for you. However, I don't have time to chat with you right now. Are you sure you have at least PHP 5.3? You can call `phpinfo();` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after regrouping and trying completely different code (because fetch just wasn't working, no idea why) I was able to complete my query function using this:

```
function run_query($query)
{    
  $out = '';
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=test;dbname=test","test","test");
  $out = $db->query("$query")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return $out;
}
```

Thanks to all for your help.